# C# ticks to datetime and format

Tags: c#, datetime

How can I convert ticks to datetime and format them to "ss:fff"?
My code:

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private DispatcherTimer timer;
        private long _ticks = 0;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Start(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime start = DateTime.UtcNow;
            timer = new DispatcherTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1), DispatcherPriority.Normal, delegate
            {
                DateTime current = DateTime.UtcNow;
                TimeSpan elapsed = current - start;
                this.Show.Text = elapsed.TotalMinutes.ToString("00:00.000");
            }, this.Dispatcher);
            timer.Start();
        }

        private void Stop(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            timer.Stop();
        }
    }
```

It worked properly on mono (I think, I tried something like this and it worked), but it doesn't work on windows. What's wrong?

Comment: We need a bit more information than that.  What is the error message that you are getting?

Comment: I hope that code is being used to show how much DispatchTimer can *drift* and *not for [other] useful purposes*...

Comment: "It doesn't work" doesn't describe what's going wrong...

Comment: I'm doing a timer app. When I click the start button, it just shows 00:000 (but it should be running).

Comment: Did you Start the timer?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're not using the Stopwatch class? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx

Comment: @Brook, I don't know if that's the right way to do it, I tried using stopwatch but then I thought it would be simpler counting ticks and then converting them more efficient?

Comment: @bah: If you decompile the Stopwatch class and look at the guts you'll find that it's using a `long` of ticks as its primary counter.  I think it's got to be pretty close to what you're trying to do.  If not, you might just want to look at the code for inspiration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use a DateTime format anyway if the operation takes longer than a minute  (because the `"ss"` format will show `09` for `69` seconds.

This adjusts the elapsed time correctly for drift.

```
DateTime start = DateTime.UtcNow;
timer = new DispatcherTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1), DispatcherPriority.Normal, delegate
{
    DateTime current = DateTime.UtcNow;
    TimeSpan elapsed = current - start;
    this.Show.Text = elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString ("00.000 seconds"); // a double converted to string.
}, this.Dispatcher);
```

Edit:

Your code doesn't show you calling `timer.Start ()` to actually start the timer.

It also doesn't show how you keep the timer from being garbage collected: `this.elapsedtimer = timer;`

Edit 2:
The `TotalSeconds.ToString ("00.000 seconds")` uses this overload of [Double.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94.aspx).

Comment: How does that converter work? (I mean the format in ToString method)
Also, wouldn't be faster to count ticks and then convert them?

Comment: It would be faster, but it won't work.  ;-)  Dispatcher timer isn't granular enough to execute your code 1 (100 nanosecond) tick at a time.  Did you know a .net tick is not the same thing as 1/1000 of a second?

Comment: See Edit 2: The TotalSeconds.ToString ("00.000 seconds") uses an overload of Double.ToString.

Comment: Ok, this worked 
new DateTime(elapsed.Ticks).ToString("ss:fff");
but why this doesn't work if I use ticks which I count myself?

Comment: "A single tick represents one hundred nanoseconds or one ten-millionth of a second. There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond." - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx  Timers are not precise enough.  You can try to count milliseconds, but you can't count ticks yourself.

Comment: Ohhh, I see, I'll have to use stopwatch then. :)